# How to draw a pretty dog leash from A to B?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fun

I need help to draw a dog leash from A to B that seems to be 8m long. The house is 3 by 5 m.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) rectangle (5,3) ;

\fill (1,3) circle (1pt) node[anchor=south] {$A$} ;

\begin{scope}[shift={(7,4)}]
\node {\includegraphics[scale=.2]{idefix}} ;
\fill[red] (-.26,-.02) circle (.3pt) node[anchor=west] {$B$} ;
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\draw (a) -- (b);` ?

Comment: \usepackage{prettydogleash}

Comment: For instance a metal chain would be an interesting problem for 3D modeling software.

Comment: @percusse: That way it is not long enough (8 m).

Comment: That's pretty much a two-point boundary value problem.

Comment: You could draw a straight line and add a circle to indicate a rectrator (or however this is called in english) ;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You could adapt the `magentic tape` shape from the TiKZ library for that purpose!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question is interesting. So you want a "loose" curve which joins points (A) and (B) and whose length is 8 units.

Obviously, the difficult part is to ensure that the length is 8 units (or at least close to that amount). The general problem depends on which curve is chosen (See Wikipedia's [arc length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length) article), but in general there is no closed solution.

First I tried to draw a circunference arc and trying to calculate (with paper and pencil) the required angle and radius to provide a length of 8, given that the chord (distance (A)--(B)) is 6 with your current settings. After a while, I was fed up (too much time since I used paper and pencil for the last time :-)) and went for another approach.

Through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443065/fast-bezier-curve-length-python-library) I found a python library which can compute the length of a Bezier curve (which is also a difficult problem usually solved by approximation), and after some trial and error, I found a solution which is aesthetically pleasing and has approximately 8 units of length as required:

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) rectangle (5,3) ;
\coordinate (A) at (1,3);
\coordinate (B) at (7,4);

\fill (A) circle (1pt) node[anchor=south] {$A$} ;

\begin{scope}[shift={(B)}]
%\node (idefix) {{idefix}} ;
\fill[red] (-.26,-.02) circle (.3pt) node[anchor=west] {$B$} ;
\end{scope}

\draw[blue,thick] (A) .. controls (4,6) and (8,0) .. (B);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Length computation:

```
>>> from pyx import path, unit
>>> bez = path.curve(1,3,4,6,8,0,7,4)
>>> unit.tocm(bez.arclen())
7.955089832696614
```

**Update**: To give a more natural look to the rope, and under the assumption that its lenght will not change too much, a "random steps" decoration can be used:

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations,decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) rectangle (5,3) ;
\coordinate (A) at (1,3);
\coordinate (B) at (7,4);

\fill (A) circle (1pt) node[anchor=south] {$A$} ;

\begin{scope}[shift={(B)}]
%\node (idefix) {{idefix}} ;
\fill[red] (-.26,-.02) circle (.3pt) node[anchor=west] {$B$} ;
\end{scope}

\draw[blue,thick,decorate,decoration={random steps}, rounded corners=1mm] (A) .. controls (4,6) and (8,0) .. (B);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 5):

Can you use a rope?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) rectangle (5,3) ;

\fill (1,3) circle (1pt) node[anchor=south] (a) {$A$} ;

\begin{scope}[shift={(7,4)}]
\node (b){\includegraphics[scale=.2]{dog}} ;
\fill[red] (-.26,-.02) circle (.3pt) node[anchor=west] {$B$} ;
\end{scope}

\draw[use Hobby shortcut,thick,tension=0.5,smooth]([out angle=30]a.south) .. (2,3.6) .. (2.5,3.7) .. (3,4)
       .. (3.5,3.7) .. (4,3.7) .. (5,3.9) .. (6,3.5) .. ([in angle=160]b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]